# Deploy failed in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, emulation, device

I have [Toradex Colibri Evaluation Board](http://developer.toradex.com/products/colibri-evaluation-board). I have started studying the board. The board has `Windows Embedded Compact 7` which needs `Visual Studio 2008`. I have downloaded the `Visual Studio 2008` along with all the updates and the `SDK` required for Toradex. I have written a simple `Hello World` program and trying to deploy it on `Colibri Evaluation Board` but it gives following error:

```
----Deploy started: Project: TestC++, Configuration: Debug Pocket PC 2003 (ARMV4) ------
----Device Emulator is not detected. Install the Device Emulator.-----
```

I have searched a lot about device emulators but didn't find the correct results. Does anyone have any idea about how to install device emulator in visual 2008 for `Toradex Colibri Evaluation Board`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you don't require any other emulator. It is installed by default when you install visual studio and SDK of Toradex.

When you are creating a project, make sure to select platform SDK & it should be on right column. Before deploying the solution, make sure your device is connected. You can check it in device manager.